# Turn off tomcat logging

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I want to turn off tomcat's logs jvm.stderr and jvm.stdout which have been set in the wrapper.properties, I've commented these lines out but that just redirects the logs to be written to the root tomcat folder.

The reason for turning them off is that these logs do not seem to have any sort of size control so I have a situation where they are getting too big and causing problems.

Is it possible to totally disable them or at least put in place some sort of management to stop the files getting too big.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the logs locations to /dev/null in the wrapper.properties? Alternatively, on if you're on Windows try the [/dev/null equivalent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/dev-null-in-windows/313236)

Comment: Thats the problem this is on windows 2003 server :(

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to a stackoverflow conversation about /dev/null in Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried putting it into startup.bar and/or wrapper.properties at the end of wrapper.cmd_line but the logs still get created :(

Comment: put > NUL into the log locations as you said, made the mistake of just doingt cmd_line previously, thanks very much for your help