# Cross platform /dev/null in Python

Tags: python

I'm using the following code to hide stderr on Linux/OSX for a Python library I do not control that writes to stderr by default:

```
f = open("/dev/null","w")
zookeeper.set_log_stream(f)
```

Is there an easy cross platform alternative to /dev/null?  Ideally it would not consume memory since this is a long running process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [/dev/null in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/dev-null-in-windows)

Comment: @msw: I don't think so, Python has more ways you can deal with this issue.

Comment: **note**: ■ hand-written null file object might actually be **slower** than `open(os.devnull)` according to user https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944391/5267751 ■ if you want to redirect stdout there's a special solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47419332/5267751

Answer (score 183, accepted):

How about [os.devnull](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.devnull) ?

```
import os
f = open(os.devnull,"w")
zookeeper.set_log_stream(f)
```

Answer (score 49):

```
class Devnull(object):
    def write(self, *_): pass

zookeeper.set_log_stream(Devnull())
```

Opening `os.devnull` is fine too of course, but this way every output operation occurs (as a noop) "in process" -- no context switch to the OS and back, and also no buffering (while some buffering is normally used by an `open`) and thus even less memory consumption.

Comment: I understand that using  os.devnull may produce some overhead. But if one uses your object what if the zookeeper object calls other methods then `write` of its  log_stream file object? Maybe it calls the `writelines` method? Then there is an exception.

Comment: This doesn't work when you need a *real* file, e.g. one with `fileno()`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart For that, I suppose you could create the file descriptor lazily on request, using `os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)` and yielding the same fd for subsequent calls to `fileno` (since all data are discarded anyway)

Comment: You'll also need `close()`

Comment: @shoosh Would inhering from `io.IOBase` and just overwrite `write()` as above do the trick? That would provide all the methods clients might expect.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.devnull
'nul'
```

Comment: Just to clarify: 'nul' is given on Windows. Linux will return '/dev/null'.

Answer (score 5):

Create your own file-like object which doesn't do anything?

```
class FakeSink(object):
    def write(self, *args):
        pass
    def writelines(self, *args):
        pass
    def close(self, *args):
        pass
```

Comment: Idiomatically, you're right, but 'self' is just another parameter and will be passed in as the first element of `args`.  As we don't use any of the parameters, the only reason to care is aesthetic.  I'll fix it...

Comment: Some operations also need 'fileno'

Answer (score 3):

Cheap solution warning!

```
class DevNull():
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.closed = False
    self.mode = "w"
    self.name = "<null>"
    self.encoding = None
    self.errors = None
    self.newlines = None
    self.softspace = 0
  def close(self):
    self.closed == True
  @open_files_only
  def flush(self):
    pass
  @open_files_only
  def next(self):
    raise IOError("Invalid operation")
  @open_files_only
  def read(size = 0):
    raise IOError("Invalid operation")
  @open_files_only
  def readline(self):
    raise IOError("Invalid operation")
  @open_files_only
  def readlines(self):
    raise IOError("Invalid operation")
  @open_files_only
  def xreadlines(self):
    raise IOError("Invalid operation")
  @open_files_only
  def seek(self):
    raise IOError("Invalid operation")
  @open_files_only
  def tell(self):
    return 0
  @open_files_only
  def truncate(self):
    pass
  @open_files_only
  def write(self):
    pass
  @open_files_only
  def writelines(self):
    pass

def open_files_only(fun):
  def wrapper(self, *args):
    if self.closed:
      raise IOError("File is closed")
    else:
      fun(self, *args)
  return wrapper
```

Comment: I threw in a decorator just for fun :D

Comment: Also need __enter__ and __exit__ ?

Answer (score 0):

Also return the amount of bytes "written" (like `write` does):

```py
import types

f = types.SimpleNamespace(write=len)
zookeeper.set_log_stream(f)
```