# Python parallel subprocess commands while suppressing output

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, subprocess

I am doing a simple ip scan using ping in python. I can run commands in parallel as demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533458/python-threading-multiple-bash-subprocesses) answer. However, I cannot suppress the output since it uses [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), and I can't use [check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) since the process returns with a exit status of 2 if a host is down at a certain ip address, which is the case for most addresses. Using a Pipe is also out of the question since too many processes are running concurrently.

Is there a way to run these child processes in python concurrently while suppressing output? Here is my code for reference:

```
def ICMP_scan(root_ip):
  host_list = []
  cmds = [('ping', '-c', '1', (root_ip + str(block))) for block in range(0,256)]
  try:
      res = [subprocess.Popen(cmd) for cmd in cmds]
      for p in res:
        p.wait()
  except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about piping the process output to `/dev/null`.

Basing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929899/cross-platform-dev-null-in-python):

```
import os

devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')

subproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

Comment: Thanks, specifying stdout suppresses output and also is able to run in parallel. However, in order to do anything with the ping responses, I have to specify the output stdout=somefile.txt, which means that I have to parse the data with regex after the operations. This is fine, but seems a little hacky... is there a better approach? if not, I will mark the answer complete

Comment: @Stuart in your question, you said "Using a Pipe is also out of the question". when you're launching a subprocess, AFAIK your options are 1. inherit stdout (which your question is about avoiding) 2. pipe stdout (which you've said you don't want to do) 3. pipe it to a file (which is what you're talking about now) or 4. pipe it to a special file, like dev/null (which is what I demonstrate in my answer). does that clarify things?