# R Batch Mode - Suppress output file

Tags: r

I have some scripts that I run using R's batch mode.

```
/usr/bin/R CMD BATCH --vanilla --no-timing ~/scripts/R/sess_dur.R
```

I redirect the output to a file using:

```
> sink("~/scripts_output/R_output.txt",append=TRUE)
```

The problem is that when I run this script, files are created with the same name of the script and the `"out"` suffix (`sess_dur.Rout`).

There is some way to tell R not to generate these files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
R CMD BATCH --vanilla --no-timing ~/scripts/R/sess_dur.R /dev/null
```

Comment: just a note, it's the /dev/null at the end that sends the output elsewhere (the --vanilla and --no-timing options are unrelated)

Comment: I don't know why that clarification was needed. The OP wanted to start with that invocation of R.

Comment: The `/dev/null` only works for UNIX-based. For WINDOWS, an appropriate alternative for it would be `NUL` as referred in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/is-there-a-dev-null-on-windows .

Comment: I seems rather clear from the question content that the questioner was not on  a windoze box.