# How can I determine is stream is empty?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, .net-4.0, stream

I have a WCF service which is returning PDF files as a stream over a NetTcp endpoint. This is all working fine. However, if the file is not found, or if I can't find the related row in the database to retrieve the filepath then I return `Stream.Null` from the service.

However I can't seem to find a way to compare the returning stream to check and see if it is empty or not.

I have tried the following:

```
If myStream IsNot Stream.Null
    'Code to execute if stream isn't empty
End If
```

and

```
If Not streamPDF.Equals(Stream.Null)
    'Code to execute if stream isn't empty
End If
```

But neither of these work as the code just carries on into the `If` block.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried If (streamPDF.Equals(Stream.Null) <> True) Then ?

Comment: Yeah tried that. Same result. Essentially that's the same as the second condition, just formatted differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Stream.Null` is only your service scoped construct. For client you will get most probably empty stream => it will be same stream type as if you really send data.

It is strange design choice. If file doesn't exists it is "expected" exception and it should be handled with `FaultContract` and typed `FaultException`.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at this next. I was trying to avoid using an exception for it, but I think you're right. I'll give that a whirl now.

Comment: Defining a `FaultContract` and throwing a `FaultException` sorts it out nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Stream.Null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.null.aspx#Y0) field which `redirect` the stream that will not consume any [operating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa939249.aspx) [system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/dev-null-in-windows) resources.

You can use [Stream.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length.aspx) property to check whether a stream is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs on a different machine, it's normal. The null stream ("A Stream with no backing store" from the documentation) is not marshaled differently over the wire. On the client side, it's just a stream which always returns EOF.

If you need to carry some extra information, you need to find another way (other parameters /value information, exceptions), but not use the Stream itself, or use a data convention understood by both parties. For example "if the file is only 1 byte long and contains the character 255, then, it's the 'null stream'".