# std::ostream as optional (!) function parameter

Tags: c++, cout, optional-parameters, ostream

I want to declare a function which writes to `std::out` by default, but also optionally enables writing to another output stream, if any is provided. For example:

```
print_function(std::string & str, 
               std::ostream & out = std::cout, 
               std::ostream & other = nullptr) // <-- how to make it optional???
{
    out << str;
    if (other == something) // if optional 'other' argument is provided
    {
        other << str;
    }
}
```

Setting `nullprt` obviously does not work, but how can this be done?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826554/standard-no-op-output-stream

Comment: It looks to me like it would be much more natural to have two overloads, one with two arguments, and one with three arguments.

Comment: @Hurkyl: or keeping the one with 2 argument and passing a "`tee_stream`".

Comment: Having a stream swallowing the input (as in the accepting answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826554/standard-no-op-output-stream) is a terrible solution, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply use function overloading, rather than default arguments

```
// declare the functions in a header

void print_function(std::string &str);
void print_function(std::string &str, std::ostream &ostr);
void print_function(std::string &str, std::ostream &ostr, std::ostream &other);

// and in some compilation unit, define them

#include "the_header"

void print_function(std::string &str)
{
       print_function(str, std::cout);
}

void print_function(std::string &str, std::ostream &ostr)
{
     // whatever
}

void print_function(std::string & str, 
                    std::ostream &ostr, 
                    std::ostream &other)
{
    print_function(str, ostr);

    other << str;
}
```

All three versions of these functions can do anything you like.  Depending on your needs, any can be implemented using the others.

If you need to interleave logic in the three functions (e.g. statements affecting `other` need to be interleaved with statements from one of the other functions) then introduce helper functions to implement the logic in separate, more granular, parts.

Comment: This perhaps is the most simple and direct solution, which also does not require boost.

Answer (score 7):

with pointer, or `boost::optional`

```
void print_function(std::string & str, 
               std::ostream & out = std::cout, 
               std::ostream* other = nullptr)
{
    out << str;
    if (other)
    {
        *other << str;
    }
}
```

or

```
void print_function(std::string & str, 
               std::ostream & out = std::cout, 
               boost::optional<std::ostream&> other = boost::none)
{
    out << str;
    if (other)
    {
        *other << str;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd keep the `boost::optional` approach only... Or at least before the pointer-approach.

Comment: @Nawaz: Some doesn't want the dependency to boost :-( . So until `optional` is in ``std::`...

Comment: Optional references where excluded from std last I checked.

Comment: or with `std::optional` from C++17 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost::optional` or pointer, as [suggested by @Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38121846/415784). However, both approaches force you to use conditional statements in the function body.

Here is another approach whose advantage is the simplicity of the function body:

```
 void print_function(std::string & str, 
              std::ostream & out = std::cout, 
              std::ostream& other = null_stream)
{
     out << str;
     other << str;  //no "if" required here.
 }
```

And here is how you may define `null_stream` object:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/null.hpp>

boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::null_sink> null_stream {
          boost::iostreams::null_sink{} 
};
```

Here `null_stream` is a `std::ostream` which does *nothing*. There are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826554/standard-no-op-output-stream) to implement it as well.

Hope that helps.