# C++ Logging using std::ostream and std::cout

Tags: c++, logging, cout, ostream

I want to write a program and enable the user to have control over the logging of the package by setting the program to display progress or disable that.

I know that `std::cout` is an `std::ostream` with the difference that `std::cout` redirects the results to standard output.

I want my class to have an `std::ostream` member that I log everything to. Then if the user enables display, that member will be attached to `std::cout` and displays the results, otherwise it wont.

What I have in mind is something similar to this:

```
class log {
private:
    std::ostream display;
public:
    void func();
    void show_display();
}

void log::func(){
    display << "called by func";
}
void log::show_display(){
    // redirect display to standard output
}
```

Is there any way similar to above to do this? If not, how can I have similar results?

Thanks.

Comment: "with the difference that std::cout puts the results to the screen directly." - no, it writes to standard output - you can redirect that from your shell.

Comment: @NeilButterworth That's absolutely correct, I am sorry for the mistake. I will edit

Comment: You can use this for the stream that ignores the output: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11826666/951890

Comment: @VaughnCato Thanks for the suggestion, i was hoping for something that i have control over to redirect the stream to the standard output whenever i wish to do so.

Comment: You can have `display()` be a function that returns a `std::ostream&`, which is either a no-op stream, or `std::cout` based on whether logging is enabled or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stream handles aren't copyable objects, nor are there any `std::ostream` objects that you the user can instantiate. So your class as written cannot work. What you could do instead is store a pointer:

```
#include <iostream>

class log {
  std::ostream* out_;

public:
  void func() {
    if (out) { *out << "called by func"; }
    // ...
  }

  void show_display() {
    out = &std::cout;
  }

  void hide_display() {
    out = nullptr;
  }
};
```

If you plan to build a more general-purpose logging system, you should consider whether logging to a disabled output requires evaluation of operands; users may expect that a log statement such as  `log << expensive_function();` is cheap when the logging is disabled.

Comment: I gotta admit i had this in mind but was hoping for another way that does not involve checking if it isnt a `nullptr` each time i wanted to log. I might as well end up just writing a function `write` that does the checking and puts it in the stream.

Comment: @Everyone: You could also create your own logger object that doesn't write anything and unconditionally log to that and plug that in instead of the null pointer.

Comment: I think i will end up doing just that because i would have control over the thread safety issues that come up with `std::cout`