# using stream to log information in C++

Tags: c++, logging, ofstream

I have a C++ class which logs messages to a `std::ofstream`.  In the class definition is this code:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define FOO_LOG(msg) /* calls to log messages are no-op in release mode */
#else
std::ofstream log_stream;
#define FOO_LOG(msg) if (log_stream.is_open()) { log_stream << msg << std::endl; }
#endif
```

The constructor for that class has several things it checks, and in certain situations will open the log file similar to this:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
log_stream.open("output.log");
#endif
```

Then in the code, it calls the C macro like this:

```
FOO_LOG("stuff=" << stuff << " in loop counter #" << xyz)
```

It is convenient that you can pass multiple params to the `FOO_LOG()` macro.  There are obvious limitations, like when logging messages from multiple threads, but this is only used for simple logging in debug builds.

**What I want to know is whether there is a different/better way to deal with the `msg` parameter in C++?**  Is there a simpler/cleaner way to implement something similar to `FOO_LOG()` in C++?

Comment: Yes, it is. Something like `FOO_LOG(logLevel) << "stuff=" << stuff << " in loop counter #" << xyz;`.

Comment: C++11 and later, you can use a templated function with a parameter pack or a variadic macro

Comment: @S.M. Make your comment into an answer so people can comment on it.  I fail to understand how what you wrote would possibly compile.

Comment: @Stéphane What does "*something similar*" mean? Do you want to maintain the syntax at the call site? I guess implementing the whole thing as a function template called as `FOO_LOG("stuff=",  stuff, " in loop counter #", xyz)` or in the way S.M. suggests would make it possible to drop the macros completely and make it somewhat cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `#ifdef NDEBUG` everywhere in your code you can have a `#ifdef NDEBUG` at the start of the header to define other useful macros.

For me `FOO_LOG("stuff=" << stuff << " in loop counter #" << xyz);` feels a bit unnatural. I would have to keep reffering back to the macro definition to see how it's implemented. Instead you can define a macro to behave as an `std::ostream` and use it as you would any other stream. That way you can do stuff like `LOG_STREAM << "stuff=" << stuff << " in loop counter #" << xyz << std::endl;`.

For this answer I had some inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826554/standard-no-op-output-stream).

```
#include <fstream>

#define NDEBUG

//An ostream class that does nothing
class DummyStream : public std::ostream {
public:
    int overflow(int c) { return c; }
} dummyStream;

//Here we let NDEBUG define other macros.
#ifdef NDEBUG
    std::ofstream logStream;
    std::ostream& oLogStream(*(std::ostream*)&logStream);
    #define LOG_STREAM (logStream.is_open() ? oLogStream : dummyStream)
    #define OPEN_LOG(log) (logStream.is_open() ? logStream.close(), logStream.open(log, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app) : \
                                                 logStream.open(log, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app))
    #define CLOSE_LOG() (logStream.close())
#else
    #define LOG_STREAM (dummyStream)
    #define OPEN_LOG(log) //no-op
    #define CLOSE_LOG()   //no-op
#endif // NDEBUG

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //will only log if NDEBUG is defined.
    OPEN_LOG("log.txt");
    std::string stuff("stuff to log");
    for(int xyz = 0; xyz < 4; xyz++) {
        LOG_STREAM << "stuff=" << stuff << " in loop counter #" << xyz << std::endl;
    }
    CLOSE_LOG();

    //Log is not open so it will not log anything.
    stuff = "stuff to not log";
    for(int xyz = 0; xyz < 4; xyz++) {
        LOG_STREAM << "stuff=" << stuff << " in loop counter #" << xyz << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Benifits of this?**

- `LOG_STREAM` is treated more intuitively like any other stream.
- `OPEN_LOG(log)` will close already open logs before opening a new one and when NDEBUG is not define it will do nothing.
- `CLOSE_LOG()` will close a log and when NDEBUG is not define it will do nothing.
- Don't need to type `#ifdef NDEBUG ... #endif` everywhere.
- `dummyStream` can be replaced with something like `std::cout` or some other stream.

**Down side?**

You have this `DummyStream` that's just in your code and a few no-op's are performed when `LOG_STREAM` is used when `NDEBUG` is not defined.