# Is it allowed to write to a ofstream when it is not opened in c++

Tags: c++, std, ofstream

I have a code like this:

```
# in class definition
std::ofstream m_myFile;

## some where in code
m_myFile.open(filename);
```

and then in several places, I am writing to file as follow:

```
m_myFile << "some data to file"<<std::endl;
```

This is working well, now I need to add a flag to system that when not set, this file should not be created and written to. I have checked and I can run the application if I do this:

```
if(createFile)
{
      m_myFile.open(filename);
}
```

and leave the write to file as it is and I am not getting any runtime error on windows. My question is if I am not opening a file and write to its stream, what is the standard behaviour?

Should I get a run time error or the ofstream just forget about the data and not run time error?

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Constructor of the `std::ofstream` automatically opens the file. You may want to use `std::fstream`, so that you can have a choice of opening with whenever you want and with read `std::fstream::in` or write `std::fstream::out` mode.

Comment: @iammilind The point is that I need an ofstream but only some times and I don't want to go everywhere in my code to check if the file is open.

Comment: @iammilind `std::ofstream` has more than one constructor. The constructors which take a string (overloads 2 and 3 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream)) attempt to open the stream. The default constructor (overload 1) does not. That's why `std::ofstream::open` also exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard behavior is that the first write fails. This sets the `std::ofstream::badbit` and further writes are silently ignored.

This silent failure could be changed to an exception by setting `m_myFile.exceptions(std::ofstream::badbit)`, but it's off by default.

You can make any stream (even std::cout) discard its output by creating a "dev null" `streambuf` and then switching your stream to that buffer (via `.rdbuf`)

Comment: @mans Look at this topic. Both high voted answers have code examples, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243743/is-there-a-null-stdostream-implementation-in-c-or-libraries

Comment: what do you mean by fail? Does it generate any exception or run_time error? Is it allowed?

Comment: What I mean by fail is exactly what I already said: `badbit` is set. This does not generate an exception **unless** you changed the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't open the file you have a stream with a default constructed file buffer that is being written to and will get discarded when the ofstream is discarded.

Comment: is there anything bad about this? Such as consuming a lot of memory or crashing ? What would happen if buffer became full?

Comment: I'd guess yes, depending on how much you write. You could wrap everything around an object and don't write if a file isn't open. This way you won't have to worry about writing to a stream for nothing

Comment: @T.C. What do you mean? I already tested the code and it is not failing.

Comment: What I meant is that you are writing to a buffer what will never written out. You could wrap everything around a let's say Logger class and do a if (!osf.is_open()) { return ; } so you don't pay for something you don't use. The code as is won't fail, it's just can be more efficient.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Since the first write fails, further writes will not even be attempted. There is no risk at all of a buffer overrun.

Comment: @MSalters If a file is not assigned (default constructor) the underline buffer is initialized without a file. Will the sentry be set to fail on the first write ?

Comment: Yes: [If the associated file is not open, `overflow` returns 
Traits::eof() before doing anything.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/overflow)

Comment: @MSalters You are write, I missed that case