# open a file in a non existing directory c versus c++

Tags: c++, c, file, ofstream

I tried to **open a file in a non existing directory in C++** and for some reason my application didn't crash. I find that a bit "weird" because **I'm used to C, where the equivalent program does crash**. Here is my C++ version followed by the equivalent C version:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ofstream f("/home/oren/NON_EXISTING_DIR/file.txt");
    f << "lorem ipsum\n";
    f.close();
    printf("all good\n");
}
$ g++ main.cpp -o main
$ ./main
all good
```

When I try the equivalent thing with C I get a segfault:

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fl = fopen("/home/oren/NON_EXISTING_DIR/file.txt","w+t");
    fprintf(fl,"lorem ipsum\n");
    fclose(fl);
    printf("all good\n");
}
$ gcc main.c -o main
$ ./main
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is that?

Comment: Your program crashes not because it failed to open a file but because it's dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: "Not crashing" doesn't mean "it works".

Comment: No program should crash when it attempts to open a nonexistent file.  Attempting to open a nonexistent file is an ordinary failure mode that any file-opening program should handle gracefully.  C programs must check the returned pointer after calling `fopen`, and not attempt to proceed if the pointer is NULL.  C++ programs should do something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"***I'm used to C***", but then "***[...] in C++***" - well, `C++` is not `C`, but that's irrelevant here. First, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28500379/7151494) - writes to an unopened stream (which is the case here) are ignored after setting the failbit.

In your `C` example, however, the problem is that if `fopen` fais, it returns a `NULL` pointer. Then you pass it to `fprintf`. That's where the Undefined Behaviour<sup>1</sup> happens. No such thing in the `C++` example.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Do note that the `C` example is *not guaranteed to* SEGFAULT. Undefined behaviour is undefined.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of used functions is the key. In both case program fails to open file. But concept of C++ library doesn't allow it to crash in constructor, for reasons. `ofstream` actually uses the same `fopen` or similar function.
Let see what manual says:

> Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a
>          FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to
>          indicate the error.

So you HAVE to check  if returned value is NULL, otherwise you have an Undefined Behavior. `ofstream` does that for you, no undefined behavior happens during initialization of object.