# Is there a way to have a single line logging statement using the << operator become a no-op and not be compiled depending on a preprocessor macro?

Tags: c++

A common trick I'm aware of to be able to turn off and on logging is to do something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define debugLog( ... ) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define debugLog( ... )
#endif
```

This way, a debugLog() statement doesn't do anything at all and produces no compiled code when it is deactivated.

However, I'm writing a C++ app, and the logging mechanism I'm using is in the style of `std::cout` and requires using the `<<` operator.

Is there a way to make a statement like this:

```
std::cout << "Some important logging:" << foo << bar;
```

...become a no-op depending on a processor macro?

I want to keep it a single line for purposes of readability. Something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "....";
#endif
```

is unacceptable if it's littered all over my code. `#ifdef` statements are quite ugly and break apart clean indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a common trick to use a default-initialized `std::ofstream`. And there are various ways to set it up. A simple approach is just to setup a global variable:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
std::ostream& debugLog = std::cout;
#else
std::ofstream debugLog;
#endif
```

And then you use that stream for your logging:

```
debugLog << "Some important logging:" << foo << bar;
```

The good thing about your old function-style macro is that if it's a no-op, then none of the arguments will be evaluated either. The entire thing is excluded by the compiler.

By contrast, if you are streaming stuff with this approach, the arguments will (probably) always be evaluated even if the receiving stream is a no-op. That can be important to consider if the stuff you are outputting requires some processing overhead.

This could potentially be addressed by instead using a simple "stream-like" class that the compiler can easily understand does nothing. So, provided any arguments to it are deemed to have no side-effects, then the compiler could reasonably prune them out.

*e.g.*

```
struct noopstream
{
    template<class T>
    noopstream& operator<<(const T&)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

To improve the chances of actually bypassing debug stuff, another trick is this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define debugLog std::cout
#else
#define debugLog while (0) std::ofstream()
#endif
```

Now if you use `debugLog << foo` in a non-debug build, the compiler will not actually evaluate anything because of the `while (0)`.

All this being said, I generally have moved to a non-reliance on this style of debugging. In cases where streams are convenient, I use a `#ifdef` block and write things into a `ostringstream`, then pass the resulting string to my debug function.

Comment: When you mention processing overhead, are you talking about the arguments being something like a function call that would need to be evaluated, or are you also talking about the processing overhead of the `<<` operating being evaluated for each argument?

Comment: No, I mean the evaluation of the arguments, if the compiler is unable to determine there are no side-effects, or know that the stream will error and do nothing. That itself may be a side-effect. You will have to experiment. You could help the compiler by writing your own pass-through stream-like interface instead, maybe: `struct noopstream { template<class T> noopstream& operator<<(const T&) { return *this; } };`

Comment: I've updated the answer, after recalling a little trick I've used before.

Comment: I like that little trick. And it works with my personal coding style, which includes _always_ using curly braces after any control statement, for precisely these sorts of reasons.

Comment: I think the problem with the "if (0)" repalcement can be fixed if you use "while (0)" instead.

Comment: That's a good point. Off the top of my head, I can't think of a way that could produce unexpected behavior depending on the surrounding code.

Comment: Oh, thanks @gerum it seems so obvious, but only after you point it out! ;) The whole approach still feels like a hack, but that's a big improvement. I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `badbit` of the `cout`:

```
...

int main()
{
#ifndef DEBUG
    std::cout.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
#endif

    std::cout << "Some logging ..." << std::endl;
}
```

It has some downsides. You can explore alternative options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455079/6628488).

Comment: This has a _lot_ of downsides. By disabling `std::cout` it's rendered useless for anything other than debugging. Even if you were to use `std::cerr` for debugging instead, then the problem remains that you have devoted an entire standard stream to debugging-only, so you couldn't use that for ordinary errors. Note that you've gotten the preprocessor logic backwards too. You meant `#ifndef DEBUG`.

Comment: @paddy Thanks for your comment. I agree with both of your tips. For the first one, I tried to mention that there are some downsides and give a helpful link. And for the second one, I fixed my answer.