# How to force Logstash to reparse a file?

Tags: file, logstash

I installed Logstash to parse apache files. It took me quite q while to get the settings right and I always tried on real logs. I noticed (as the documentation says) that logstash "remembers" where it was in a file. Now my setings are Ok and I would like Logstash to "forget". This seems harder than I though. I already did the following:

- used: `start_position => "beginning"`
- deleted the complete "data" folder from elastissearch (and stopped it first)
- looked at which files where opened by logstash with `lsof -p PID` and deleted everything which was promising (in my case `/tmp/jffi*.tmp`)

Still Logstash does not forget and parse only "fresh" files in the folder where the logs are

Any ideas?

Comment: Latest logstash version I found it in: `/opt/logstash/data/plugins/inputs/file`

Answer (score 142):

By default logstash writes the position is last was on to a logfile which usually resides in `$HOME/.sincedb`. Logstash can be fooled into believing it never parsed the logfile by specifying `/dev/null` as `sincedb_path`.

Here the part of the documentation [Input File](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html).

> Where to write the since database (keeps track of the current position
>   of monitored log files). Defaults to the value of environment variable
>   "$SINCEDB_PATH" or "$HOME/.sincedb".

**Config Example**

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/tmp/logfile_to_analyse"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
```

Comment: On windows you can use `sincedb_path => "NUL"` to get the same effect. Detailes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/dev-null-in-windows)

Comment: If the files are quite old (more then 24h) very useful is to add option `ingnore_older => 0` so logstash will  take them no matter of date. By default if the files are older then 24h will be ignored.

Comment: @mtfk: Wow awesome find!  Thanks for pointing out `ignore_older => 0` works in logstash!  I've been jammed by the same problem as the questioner.  Seems to be a non-obvious find!  (googling "ignore_older" and "logstash" only bring up pages on filebeat, I couldn't find any trace of how to deal with this in logstash)

Comment: How to add this while using filebeat

Comment: @SunilkumarRamamurthy I believe if you leave out the option ``ignore_older`` in your filebeat configuration, filbeat is forced to read the entire file again https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#ignore-older

Answer (score 21):

The plugin file store history of "tailing" in sincedb file, default : under $HOME/.sincedb* , see http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/inputs/file#sincedb_path

The since db file contains line look like :

```
[inode] [major device number] [minor device number] [byte offset]
```

So, if you want to parse again a complete file, you need to :

- delete sindedb files
- **OR** only delete the corresponding line in sincedb file, check the inode number before of your file (`ls -i yourFile  | awk '{print $1}'` )
- And restart Logstash

With the key `start_position => "beginning"`, Logstash will analyze all the file.

Example of a sincedb file :

- name : `.sincedb_7a7413a84171aa550d5318c17fd756e9`: the name contains sincedb_ and a MD5 (Digest::MD5.hexdigest) of all directory in key path (http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/inputs/file#path). See code of plugin file: https://github.com/logstash/logstash/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb#L105

Comment: Regarding `start_position => "beginning"`, the documentation says:  >This option only modifieds "first contact" situations where a file is new and not seen before. If a file has already been seen before, this option has no effect.

Answer (score 11):

Logstash will keep the record in `$HOME/.sincedb_*`. You can delete all the `.sincedb` and restart logstash, Logstash will reparse the file.

Answer (score 10):

Combining all answers, guess this is the best way to parse files. I did the same for my testing.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/access_log"
    start_position => beginning
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    ignore_older => 0
  }
}
```

For a quick test, instead of `ignore_older` , you can also `touch /tmp/access_log` to change timestamp of the file.

Comment: be aware that adding the config `ignore_older => 0` will do the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using logstash-forwarder check your home for `.logstash-forwarder` file instead:

```
{
  "/var/log/messages": {
    "source": "/var/log/messages",
    "offset": 43715,
    "inode": 12967,
    "device": 51776
  }
}
```

Comment: If installed as a package, check `/var/lib/logstash-forwarder/`.

Answer (score 3):

After deleting `$HOME/.sincedb_*` it still wasn't ingesting data for me.

After trying a bunch of things I removed all but the main `.conf` file from `/etc/logstash/conf.d` and restarted Logstash, and everything worked. I can only assume there was something in one of the `.conf` files that logstash was silently hanging on.

Comment: As I recall, I later turned on some debugging flag and it told me why it was angry rather than silently hanging. I think it was looking for a version number in the data but sometimes the data did not have a number in it. The check to find out what the number was would crash if it wasn't a number, so I had to first test it was a number then ask what number was it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually reparsing each time is very costly if the file has large data in it. So you need to be careful before doing this.
If we want to force it to reparse again then set the parameter inside input block

```
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
```

This option will not be storing the .sincedb file and logstash will reparse each time. But if you want to reparse occasionaly not each time then what you can do is that delete manually the .sinceDb path which is created on parsing the file. Generally it is present in the home directory as a hidden file if you are not a root user otherwise in root directory.
You can also set the sincedb_path to some other location to trace this file easily.

```
sincedb_path => "/home/shubham/sinceDB/productsSince.db"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid messing with the logstash options I've found that renaming or removing the existing log file and creating a *new* file from the old file contents will trick logstash into re-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in my home dir but after deleting it, logstash refused to re-pick the existing log files. The way I got it to work was to add

```
sincedb_path => "/opt/elk/sincedb/"
```

to my file plugin. I think to reset each time, just change the path of sincedb_path

Answer (score 0):

if you use tar.gz install filebeat, you can delete this file, `$FilebeatPath/data/registry/filebeat/data.json`, and rerun the filebeat

Answer (score 0):

Try by deleting `/var/lib/logstash` folder in your ENV

Answer (score 0):

As seen on:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path

You can see that Logstash is going to save a sincedb file keeping track of which file it already has seen and processed till which line.

If you want to get rid of the existing sincedb file and you do not have defined the sincedb_path yourself you can find it in

```
<path.data>/plugins/inputs/file
```

By default <path.data> holds the value

```
LOGSTASH_HOME/data
```

By default LOGSTASH_HOME holds the value

```
/var/lib/logstash
```

It is best to define the sincedb_path if you want to have full control of it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
sincedb_clean_after => 0
start_position => "beginning"
```

Answer (score -1):

logstash version 5 new directory is in

```
<path.data>/plugins/inputs/file
```

path.data definition is in logstash.yml