# Logstash CSV is not working

Tags: csv, logstash

I am trying to read CSV data in logstash, but some how logstash isn't able to split strings considering them as csv

**logstash config**

```
input {
    file {
        path => [ "/root/logstash/temp.csv" ]
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ['A','B','C','D','E']
    }
}

output {
    stdout { }
}
```

**Test CSV file**

```
p,q,r,s,t

p,q,r,s,t

p,q,r,s,t

p,q,r,s,t

p,q,r,s,t

p,q,r,s,t
```

**Output of logstash**

```
2014-04-23T13:26:53.415+0000 0.0.0.0 p,q,r,s,t

2014-04-23T13:26:53.416+0000 0.0.0.0 p,q,r,s,t

2014-04-23T13:26:53.416+0000 0.0.0.0 p,q,r,s,t

2014-04-23T13:26:53.417+0000 0.0.0.0 p,q,r,s,t

2014-04-23T13:26:53.417+0000 0.0.0.0 p,q,r,s,t

2014-04-23T13:26:53.418+0000 0.0.0.0 p,q,r,s,t
```

Can somebody help me with this issue?

1) I have tried replacing single quote with double quotes in Columns

2) I tried with different data

I am expecting columnar output as mentioned in this link https://blog.trifork.com/2014/01/28/using-logstash-elasticsearch-and-kibana-to-monitor-your-video-card-a-tutorial/

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095020/use-logstash-csv-filter-doesnt-work/31159424#31159424

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the output you need to specify the codec.

For example, with your configuraiton,

```
input {
   file {
       path => [ "/root/logstash/temp.csv" ]
       start_position => "beginning"
   }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ['A','B','C','D','E']
    }
}

output {
    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Add the **codec** and then you can get what you want.

```
{
   "message" => [
    [0] "p,q,r,s,t"
],
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-04-24T02:57:37.099Z",
         "A" => "p",
         "B" => "q",
         "C" => "r",
         "D" => "s",
         "E" => "t"
}
```

Comment: It worked. As per the link mentioned, I was expecting stdout to also have the columnar o/p. Thanks.

Comment: @Ben, I too am just discovering logstash,and am following the same tutorial, What I noticed is that logstash wouldn't print anything on the console until the file contents changed/Updated. So is it the way it has to work or am I missing something? - Am on logstash version 1.4.2

Comment: The defualt setting of Logstash file filter will start parsing from the end. You have to specific the settings. FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546900/how-to-force-logstash-to-reparse-a-file/21372403#21372403