# logstash forwarder dead time not working for apache

Tags: logstash-forwarder

I am trying to send apache access log for last 24 hour without much luck. Can someone point out what am i missing here? It is working fine for IIS.

```
{"paths": [ "/var/www/logs/access.log" ],    "fields": { "type": "apache", "virtualhost": "zzz.gov.mv" },    "dead time": "24h" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to also reset the `since_db` as statet in this answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25119894/2854723

You can also define the parameter `start_position` to `beginning` (also handled in the linked answer).