# logstash file input glob not working

Tags: logstash, glob

I'm starting to explore logstash and this is probably a newbie question, but as far as I have studied this should be working and it isn't.

I have a very simple configuration that just reads log files and dump them to the stdout. It works for a single file and for a list (array) of files, but if I use a glob that matches the same files, nothing happens.

I've tested the glob with a short ruby script and it lists the correct files.

Here is my configuration:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/lpacheco/*.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

output {
    stdout {}
}
```

If I run this with `--verbose` I get:

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-09-23T11:26:47.008000-0300", :message=>"Registering file input", :path=>["/home/lpacheco/*.log"], :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-09-23T11:26:47.068000-0300", :message=>"No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the file path", :sincedb_path=>"/home/.sincedb_6da9e0c63851aa9d5840ba19efd196cb", :path=>["/home/lpacheco/*.log"], :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2015-09-23T11:26:47.089000-0300", :message=>"Pipeline started", :level=>:info}
```

Nothing else happens.

I'm using:

- logstash 1.5.4
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6)
  (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision
  43786) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are apparently confronted with a [sincedb](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path)-issue. Logstash saves the last position of a logfile in a file called sincedb. The sincedb is based on the inode of the log file so that renaming or using globs doesn't have any effect.

Try this input for testing:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/lpacheco/*.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
```

From latest docs:

> Path of the sincedb database file (keeps track of the current position
>   of monitored log files) that will be written to disk. The default will
>   write sincedb files to some path matching $HOME/.sincedb* NOTE: it
>   must be a file path and not a directory path

For more information, take a look at related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546900/how-to-force-logstash-to-reparse-a-file).

Comment: Great, using "/dev/null" as the sincedb_path worked, as did specifying a file name. What's the problem with ommiting the parameter, though?

Comment: Ok, you nailed it and it is a sincedb_path issue, but I think that the actual problem is that my log file is not "live", it is a copy from our production server. I thought that using 'start_position => "beginning"' would allow me to keep reusing the file, but it didn't work. 'sincedb_path => "/dev/null"' ignores the sincedb, but is not usefull as an actual configuration. Removing the sincedb file is a better solution, I think.

Comment: You're right. `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` is for test purpose only. You should not use it in productive environments. In productive case deleting the sincedb files is a better approach in order to reparse the logs. `start_position => "beginning"` is a bit confusing in this situation and you are not the only one who stumbled upon it.

Comment: For those using Windows who want to ignore the sincedb_path, point it to `sincedb_path => "nul"` instead.