# Logstash not sending logs to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, logstash, elastic-stack

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Using the latest Logstash and ES versions:

```
Name        : elasticsearch
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 2.4.0
Release     : 1

Name        : logstash
Arch        : noarch
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 2.4.0
Release     : 1
```

I have a 2 node ES cluster.
The nodes are bound to their NICs IP in the config file (10.1.1.1, and 10.1.1.2 for the other node):

```
network.host: 10.1.1.1
```

Curling 10.1.1.1:9200 successfully responds with ES cluster info.

```
  "cluster_name": "mycluster",
  "status": "green",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 2,
  "active_primary_shards": 0,
  "active_shards": 0,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 100
```

Installed logstash on one of the nodes. Following [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html#configuring-grok-filter) with the example log data they provide.

Used the same config file in the tut but replaced "localhost" with "10.1.1.1"
[image]

I see this output with no errors:
[image]

When I look at the the ES nodes I see no indexes have been created (checking with `10.1.1.1:9200/_cat/indices?v`)

THere are no logs in /var/log/logstash

The es logs in /var/log/elasticsearch aren't touched or changed after running this command

running the log stash command with --verbose doesn't show any errors, just messages about loading filter, then just sitting at "pipeline main started" and outputs nothing.

Stopped the firewalld service, but still nothing

Edit: 
Ok so this issue was that I specified the direct path of the log file (not *.log as show in the screen shot).

According to the tutorial (and file plugin docs), specifying start_position => 0 and ignore_older => 0 should suck in the log file and any pre existing data in it, but it was not doing that. If I started the logstash process and pushed new data into the log file with echo >> logstash finally pushing data into elasticsearch.

So my question is why does it not process the log's pre existing data when specifying the direct path of a log file? Why is *.log necessary for it to grab the pre existing data?

Comment: Looks like you solved the problem.  You should answer your own question.

Comment: If you are changing your ES host from localhost to something remote, you are probably running into a `sincedb` type of issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19546900/2785358