# logstash output not showing up in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I just started learning Elastic Search and trying to dump IIS logs to ES via logstash and see how it looks in Kibana.
Have set up all the 3 agents succuessfully and they run witout errors. But when I run logstash on my stored log files, the logs doesnt show up in Kibana. 
(Am using ES5.0 which doesnt have the 'head' _plugin)

This is the output I see in logstash command.

```
    Sending Logstash logs to C:/elasticsearch-5.0.0/logstash-5.0.0-rc1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties.
06:28:26.067 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>["http://localhost:9200"]}}
06:28:26.081 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
06:28:26.501 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date", "include_in_all"=>false}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
06:28:26.573 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["localhost:9200"]}
06:28:26.717 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
06:28:26.736 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Pipeline main started
06:28:26.857 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

But kibana doesnt show up any indexes. I am a newbie here and am not sure whats going on internally. Could you please help me understand what is wrong here.

[image]

Logstash Config file:

```
input { 
    file {
        type => "iis-w3c"
        path => "C:/Users/ras/Desktop/logs/logs/LogFiles/test/aug1/*.log"
      }
}
filter {  
    grok {
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{WORD:serviceName} %{WORD:serverName} %{IP:serverIP} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:uriStem} %{NOTSPACE:uriQuery} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IPORHOST:clientIP} %{NOTSPACE:protocolVersion} %{NOTSPACE:userAgent} %{NOTSPACE:cookie} %{NOTSPACE:referer} %{NOTSPACE:requestHost} %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:subresponse} %{NUMBER:win32response} %{NUMBER:bytesSent} %{NUMBER:bytesReceived} %{NUMBER:timetaken}"]
      }
     mutate {
    ## Convert some fields from strings to integers
    #
    convert => ["bytesSent", "integer"]
    convert => ["bytesReceived", "integer"]
    convert => ["timetaken", "integer"]

    ## Create a new field for the reverse DNS lookup below
    #
    add_field => { "clientHostname" => "%{clientIP}" }

    ## Finally remove the original log_timestamp field since the event will
    #   have the proper date on it
    #
    remove_field => [ "log_timestamp"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Instead of head, you can use kopf, which I prefer compared to head. But I don't know if it's available for ES 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the name of the index present in Elasticsearch with a plugin like kopf, or with the endpoint `_cat/indices/`, which you can access directly via a browser at `[ip of ES]:9200/_cat/indices` or via curl: `curl [ip of ES]:9200/_cat/indices`.

---

With Kibana you have to provide a pattern of the index names, which is by default `logstash-*`, as shown in your screenshot. This default is used in Kibana since, in the elasticsearch output plugin for logstash, the default index pattern is `logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` ([cf doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index)), which will be use to name the index created with this plugin.

But in you case, the plugin is configured with `index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM}"`. So the index created will be of the `iis-w3c-%{+YYYY.MM}` format. So you'll have to replace `logstash-*` by `iis-w3c-*` in the field `Index name or pattern`

Comment: When I do _cat/indices/,  I only get the text as **yellow open .kibana HUMxXPMtS0-MBNQtyj5G6g 1 1 1 0 3.2kb 3.2kb** . I am not seeing any index created with name as iis*.

Comment: @Raghav So the problem is with Logstash. If Logstash has already read the file (for example with just stdout), Logstash will not read again the files if you relaunch it. Take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25119894/6113627