# How do I force rebuild log's data in filebeat 5

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have filebeats **5.x** ship logs to logstash.

How do I reset the “file pointer” in filebeat

This is a similar problem to

- [How to force Logstash to reparse a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546900/how-to-force-logstash-to-reparse-a-file58)
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-i-reset-the-file-pointer-in-filebeats/49440

I cleaned all elasticsearch's data, delete the `/var/lib/filebeat/registry`. but filebeat is only shipping the new line.

change the [registry_file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.1/configuration-global-options.html#_registry_file) is invalid, the file's offset saved to new file (delete file is the same problem)

`filebeat.registry_file: registry`

Answer (score 13):

1. Stop filbeat service.
2. Rename the register file - usually found in       /var/lib/filebeat/registry
3. Start filbeat service.

> sudo service filbeat stop
>
> mv /var/lib/filebeat/registry /var/lib/filebeat/registry.old
>
> sudo service filbeat start

Comment: For Mac OS Users who installed through homebrew, it's at `/usr/local/var/lib/filebeat/registry`

Answer (score 9):

The Filebeat agent stores **all** of its state in the registry file. The location of the registry file should be set inside of your configuration file using the [`filebeat.registry_file`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-global-options.html#_registry_file) configuration option.

I *recommend specifying an absolute path* in this option so that you know exactly where the file will be located. If you use a relative path then the value is interpreted relative to the [`${path.data}`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/directory-layout.html) directory. On Linux installations, when started as a service or started using the `filebeat.sh` wrapper, `path.data` is set to `/var/lib/filebeat`.

After deleting this registry file, Filebeat will begin reading all files from the beginning (unless you have configured a prospector with [`tail_files: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#_tail_files).

If you continue to have problems, I recommend looking at the Filebeat log file which will contain a line stating where the registry file is located. For example:

`2017/01/18 18:51:31.418587 registrar.go:85: INFO Registry file set to: /var/lib/filebeat/registry`

Comment: stop filebeat's server, then delete the '/var/lib/filebeat/registry'. and it's work. it's my problem, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned here, stopping the filebeat service, deleting the registry file(s) and restarting the service is correct.

I just wanted to add for Windows users, if you haven't specified a unique location for the `filebeat.registry_file`, it will likely default to `${path.data}/registry` which is somewhat confusingly the `C:\ProgramData\filebeat` directory as mentioned by the folks at Elastic.

In my case I had to [show hidden files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files) before it was displayed.

Comment: Just wanted to point to anyone who's like me, it's the `ProgramData` folder and NOT `Program Files`