# simple logstash command is not working

Tags: logstash

It is working for auth.log but not working for authcopy.log. There is no error message. There is no output.

This is working.

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { file { path => "/var/log/auth.log" } }'
```

output:

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "removed",
          "path" => "/var/log/auth.log",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-01-10T23:51:39.912Z,
       "message" => "Jan 10 20:17:55 removed sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root"
}

...
```

This is not working.

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { file { path => "/var/log/authcopy.log" } }'
```

There is no error message. There is no output.

Copied auth.log to authcopy.log

```
sudo cp /var/log/auth.log /var/log/authcopy.log

sudo chmod 777 /var/log/authcopy.log

ls -l /var/log/auth*.log
```

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root   root 391617 Jan 10 19:30 /var/log/authcopy.log

-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  395465 Jan 10 20:13 /var/log/auth.log

Comment: Have you checked /var/logs/logstash? No error log there? Your output is a file plugin?

Comment: Logtash remember what files it has read and where it has stopped reading. So once logstash has read a file and it does not change, opening this file again will not output anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25119894/6113627

Comment: @baudsp thanks, it worked, sincedb_path => "/dev/null" start_position => "beginning".