# Logstash not showing output on stdout

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

This is my logstash.conf

```
input {
 file {
  type => "java"
  path => "/home/user/ELK/logs/logstash-tutorial-dataset"
 }
}

output {
 stdout {
  codec => rubydebug
 }
}
```

when trying to start logstash using command:

```
./bin/logstash -f logstash.conf --config.reload.automatic
```

it is not giving any output on command prompt. (apart from below lines)

```
[2018-02-19T15:06:46,910][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting 
pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, 
"pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-02-19T15:06:46,962][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline 
started succesfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#
<Thread:0x1dd165a4 sleep>"}
[2018-02-19T15:06:46,988][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines 
running {:count=>1, :pipelines=>["main"]}
```

Can you please tell what could be the issue ?

OR

is this expected behaviour?

(i expect it to print output after reading from file configured in input section)

Comment: Perhaps it's this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25119894/6113627

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these two lines after the path:

```
start_position = beginning
sincedb_path = "/dev/null"
```