# Logstash hangs when trying to send data to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This is the output i have in my `.config` file for Logstash:

```
output {

   elasticsearch {
      document_type => "apache"

}}
```

When output is set to `stdout {}` it's working perfectly.
I have Elasticsearch running locally with no issues.
When i run the command:

`sudo ./logstash -f sample_1.conf --debug`

Logstash just hangs.
This is what i got in the logs using `--debug`:

```
[DEBUG] 2018-03-04 03:28:56.245 [pool-2-thread-2] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[DEBUG] 2018-03-04 03:28:56.255 [pool-2-thread-2] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[DEBUG] 2018-03-04 03:28:58.448 [[main]<file] file - _globbed_files: /usr/share/logstash/bin/log_file.txt: glob is: ["/usr/share/logstash/bin/log_file.txt"]
[DEBUG] 2018-03-04 03:28:59.353 [Ruby-0-Thread-12: /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:617] pipeline - Pushing flush onto pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x34284e61@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:246 sleep>"}
[DEBUG] 2018-03-04 03:29:01.268 [pool-2-thread-2] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[DEBUG] 2018-03-04 03:29:01.268 [pool-2-thread-2] jvm - collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[DEBUG] 2018-03-04 03:29:04.354 [Ruby-0-Thread-12: /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:617] pipeline - Pushing flush onto pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x34284e61@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:246 sleep>"}
```

These lines just repeat themselves again and again indefinitely.
Both Logstash and Elasticsearch versions are 6.2.2

What could be the problem?

Comment: Logstash does not reparse files which have already been parsed. So if you're reading a file that does not change, the next time logstash runs, all the line previously parsed won't be parsed again. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546900/how-to-force-logstash-to-reparse-a-file.

Comment: Have you checked there's data in elasticsearch? Also you can have more than one output, so you could have stdout and elasticsearch at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

From version 6.0, ElasticSearch removed document types or mapping types. You can remove the document_type and try again.

Refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html for more details.

Comment: so just have `elasticsearch` empty?

Comment: if you have it empty, the defaults are applied. you can have other settings specific to your es instance but the document_type does not apply any more.