# Logstash: Simplest pipeline possible not working

Tags: logstash

Using `logstash 2.4` (I have my reasons) on `Ubuntu 16.04`

```
root@logbox:/etc/logstash/conf.d# ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  2 19:53 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov  2 15:46 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  277 Nov  2 19:52 01_01_input.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  604 Nov  2 19:48 03_02_output_pa_http.conf


root@logbox:/etc/logstash/conf.d# cat *.conf

input {

  stdin {}

  file {
    path => "/usr/share/logstash/files/production_input.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    # codec => plain { charset => "ISO-8859-1" }
    codec => json
    # add_field => [ 'redis_db', '10' ]
  }



}
output {

  stdout {}

}


root@logbox:/etc/logstash/conf.d# ls -al /usr/share/logstash/files/production_input.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11910 Nov  2 16:09 /usr/share/logstash/files/production_input.txt
```

However...

```
vagrant@logbox:/etc/logstash/conf.d$ sudo tail -f /var/log/logstash/logstash*


Sending logstash logs to /var/log/logstash/logstash.log.

==> /var/log/logstash/logstash.log <==
{:timestamp=>"2018-11-02T19:59:52.947000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline main started"}

==> /var/log/logstash/logstash.stdout <==
{:timestamp=>"2018-11-02T19:59:52.947000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline main started"}
```

The file is not printed in `stdout`...I have tried both codecs (`json` and `plain`)

**edit**: actually it might be the case the file has been read only **once**; does this have to do with `sincedb`?
how do I force logstash to read it again? isn't `start_position => beginning` enough?

Comment: Have you tried `stdout { codec => rubydebug }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start_position` is used the first time the file is read.

If you want to force logstash to read it again, you need to add in your file input plugin conf this parameter :
`sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`

Please read this for further explanation 
[How to force Logstash to reparse a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546900/how-to-force-logstash-to-reparse-a-file)