# How to force Logstash 7 to reparse a file?

Tags: logstash

There is a similar question and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546900/how-to-force-logstash-to-reparse-a-file).

However, in 7.11 if I set `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` and start logstash I get the following error:

```
   Error: Permission denied – Permission denied
   Exception: Errno::EACCES
```

which turned out to be quite difficult to find the cause of. In other words, the solution of setting `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` doesn't work.

My OS is MacOSX and I installed logstash via brew. Is there a better way than stopping logstash each time, removing `libexec/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_XXXX` files and restarting logstash?

Comment: You could use a docker container to run logstash, this have some advantage like be able to segregate the run/ test quickly different version/ be more near to the targeted env (prod) etc... I don't know how logstash brew is deploy. Or you can get the logstash binaries directly thant brew install

Answer (score 0):

```
sincedb_path => "NULL"
```

seems to work.