# Get predefined macros from GCC without temporary files

Tags: windows, gcc, command-line, mingw, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to retrieve predefined macros from the GCC preprocessor **without having to use temporary files** (e.g. using pipes)?

There is a similar question here on StackOverflow, but all its answers make use of the command line, while I need to read mentioned data from within a process.
[GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines)

Google basically returns a lot of answers to the command line version of the question.

When I try to perform the command line trick of directing output to /dev/null on Linux or NUL on Windows using pipes:

```
RunAndGetOutput("cpp -dM -E < NUL");
```

... an error occurs:

> cpp.exe: error: <: Invalid argument
>
> cpp.exe: warning: '-x c' last input file has no effect
>
> cpp.exe: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.

When I execute the same command from the command line all is fine, and a list of defines it printed.

Is there any way I can fix this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you need a named pipe. Look up CreateNamedPipe (Windows) or mkfifo (POSIX). That way you get a special file name you can pass to GCC as an output file. The annoying bit naming it, usually based on the PID.

Comment: RunAndGetOutput is not interpreting shell metacharacters, so gcc sees a `<` on the command line and doesn't know what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly sure how `NUL` behaves under windows, but I assume it is similar to `/dev/null` in Unix/Linux: [/dev/null in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/dev-null-in-windows)

On my Ubuntu VM I can do:

```
cpp -dM -E -xc /dev/null
```

So I assume under windows you could do something like:

```
cpp -dM -E -xc NUL
```

This assumes `NUL` behaves essentially like an empty file.  If the output from `type NUL` is any indicator here, then this is hopefully the case.

Alternatively, if this doesn't work, you could do the `cpp` command with redirection within a `cmd.exe` subshell:

```
cmd.exe /C "cpp -dM -E < NUL"
```

From the point of view of `RunAndGetOutput()`, this is just a single `cmd.exe` command with a few params passed, and no pipes/redirections.  But the `cmd.exe` shell will interpret the passed string as a command, and importantly will understand how to handle the `<` redirection correctly.

---

Since you're calling the cpp preprocessor directly, the `-E` and `-xc` options are unnecessary (at least this is the case in Linux), but leaving them there won't do any harm.

Comment: @nos - yes, as always there is more than one way to do things.  But be careful - windows `echo` is a bit different - if run alone, it will print `ECHO is on.`.  To really echo a blank line, you need to do `echo.`.  So `cmd.exe /C "echo. | cpp -xc -dM -E -"` should do the trick.