# Why does PowerCmd show duplicate git commits?

Tags: git, console, console-application

I often use the windows console called **console2** and recently found **PowerCmd**, so I have been trying it out.

I create a Git repository and make and commit three changes. First the correct log in **console2**:

```
c:\code\junk>git log --pretty=oneline
015cfbec12208d7b719d523c92d0c46b726d42e6 third time lucky.
c8a9ffeb4381cd515a62937a0a50b7dc5360dbb8 Second commit
370e9cbb72feca9fb784843154f2171fefe2c656 initial commit
```

I get double the goodness using **PowerCmd**:

```
C:\code\junk>git log --pretty=oneline
[33m015cfbec12208d7b719d523c92d0c46b726d42e6[m third time lucky.
[33mc8a9ffeb4381cd515a62937a0a50b7dc5360dbb8[m Second commit
[33m370e9cbb72feca9fb784843154f2171fefe2c656[m initial commit
015cfbec12208d7b719d523c92d0c46b726d42e6 third time lucky.
c8a9ffeb4381cd515a62937a0a50b7dc5360dbb8 Second commit
370e9cbb72feca9fb784843154f2171fefe2c656 initial commit
```

Any body know whats up?

EDIT:
Tried a suggestion **--no-color** and ....

```
C:\code\junk>git log --pretty=oneline --no-color
015cfbec12208d7b719d523c92d0c46b726d42e6 third time lucky.
c8a9ffeb4381cd515a62937a0a50b7dc5360dbb8 Second commit
370e9cbb72feca9fb784843154f2171fefe2c656 initial commit
015cfbec12208d7b719d523c92d0c46b726d42e6 third time lucky.
c8a9ffeb4381cd515a62937a0a50b7dc5360dbb8 Second commit
370e9cbb72feca9fb784843154f2171fefe2c656 initial commit
```

Too funny! I like PowerCmd, maybe just not for git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [ANSI escape sequence](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) (for [ANSI colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)), and PowerCmd doesn't seem to support them (as mentioned [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powercmd/ht537TdemHo))

You can try:

```
git log --no-color
```

That would allow you to check if there still is duplicate commits when you ask for no color.

I checked: the output is always doubled, even when I set `TERM=msys`

The only way I got it to behave is by redirecting stdout to a dummy text ([not `NUL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313115/6309), but an actual dummy file)

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git log -2 --no-color --oneline >dummy
f82887f Git 2.1-rc2
764c739 Merge branch 'mb/relnotes-2.1'
```

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work - it makes me think that its trying to do something else - I just don't know what!

Comment: >git --version
git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1

Comment: @rtfminc I just tested Powercmd, and the issue is there. I have found one way to get only one output (instead of two), but the workaround isn't very practical. See my edited answer.

Comment: yes, the workaround works. Glad it wasn't me, I had TortoiseGit installed and removed it and the msysgit installed and reloaded it. Thanks for pinpointing the problem, I like having things figured out. :)