# PHP & PYTHON python code doesn't run if i run in background

Tags: php, python

I call a python script from PHP but i run script in background because i don't want to wait after script to finish, so i use `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` with `shell_exec`.
This is the code where i call:

```
shell_exec("C:\\Python27\\python C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testing.py > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

in python script i have a simple write file:

```
fileName = "temp.txt"
target = open(fileName, 'w')

for x in range(1, 59):
    target.write("test" + str(x) + "&#13;&#10;")

target.close()
```

When i call script from `PHP` with `shell_exec("C:\\Python27\\python C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testing.py");`
 it's working but webpage it's waiting after script to finish and i don't want that, so i called with `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` but now, the code doesn't run.
Any ideas why code doesn't working when i want to run in background?
Thanks!

LE:

Changed `/dev/null/` with `nul` and still no working.

Now i call `shell_exec("C:\\Python27\\python C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testing.py > NUL 2> NUL &");` and it's working but page still wating after script to finish.

Comment: possible duplicate of [/dev/null in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/dev-null-in-windows)

Comment: No, still not working with `nul` and not `/dev/null`

Comment: It is `NUL`, not `nul`. `/dev/null` is a *Linux* bit bucket, and `C:\\...` is a Windows path... you cannot mix and match Linux and Windows paths like this.

Comment: I tried with both options, still no work... It's working but it's waiting after script to finish.

Comment: Well, the entire `> NUL 2> NUL &` is a Linux command (with the Win bit bucket). As I said, you *cannot mix and match Linux and Windows stuff* like this. Outputting stuff to NUL would just be `... > NUL`. According to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background), background processes are run using `START /B [PATH_TO_EXEC]`. Do some research before asking more questions.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen you are really near the problem. You don't understand the problem is not start without CMD, i dont give a **** if a cmd jumps on my screen. Problem is `my webpage don't need to wait after script`, it's 100% clear for you which is the problem? And the problem is here about PHP, not how to start a program without cmd (your link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:
`pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));`
You can start a program without cmd and `PHP` will not wait after program to finish.