# fastest command, which accepts pipe, but generates no text on StdOut & StdErr

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe, stdout, stderr

Which command in Windows command script (.cmd) accepts pipe (so, no error "The Process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe." generated), but generates no output itself, including output to StdErr? I need to not touch normal StdErr output (keep in mind, pipe transports only StdOut). I can't use null device, due to it's not installed in the system.
For example, `command|rem` generates mentioned error. But I want no error output, except generated by `command`, so `rem` is not suitable command for needed purpose.
Main aim is the script speed. So, don't offer extensive constructions, please.

Comment: If you don't want to output anything, then why write a command in the first place? Plus: the `nul` device is always there, you can't remove it.

Comment: [/dev/null in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/313111)

Comment: I find it hard to believe you can't use nul.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm not sure that's true.  I haven't tested this, but if you remove the registry entry for the `NUL` device from the Session Manager's DOS Devices key (and then reboot) I imagine it would remove the device.  It would a dumb thing to do, but I've seen dumber.

Comment: You are right, there is no /dev/null on Windows. However, there is NUL.

Comment: The Windows XP Embedded does NOT have null.

Answer (score 0):

should be `break`(or `set/p=` ?)  as it is internal command prompt command (i.e. no external process started ) and generally do nothing.Though I suppose if you are searching for executable packed with the windows answer will be different.

Comment: `break` don't accept pipe. But `set/p=` does! Thanks for advise. Now I perform commands testing in `for` cycle. If here will be no best answer before my testing be finished, I'll post result here as my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `cd .` command is what you are looking for. I used it to create empty files. This way, `command | cd .` works and `echo Hello >&2 | cd .` show "Hello" in the screen! This works as a filter that just blocks Stdout (interesting).

Comment: unfortunately, `cd .` don't accept pipe (mentioned error appears)