# Redirecting standard error stream, haskell create process

Tags: haskell

How to using `createProcess` in haskell redirect stderr into `/dev/null` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `/dev/null` with `withFile` and set it as `std_err` in the `CreateProcess` record:

```
import System.Process
import System.IO 

main :: IO ()
main = withFile "/dev/null" WriteMode (\handle -> do
    (_,_,_,phandle) <- createProcess (shell "echo foo"){ std_err = UseHandle handle}
    waitForProcess phandle
    return ())
```

In Windows, you can use the [`NUL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/dev-null-in-windows) file.

Answer (score 2):

Not the exact solution you are looking for but one popular solution in the community is to use the `silently` package to achieve it.

You can use the function [hSilence](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.14/silently-1.2.5/src/System.IO.Silently.html#hSilence) to do want you want. In fact, internally it opens `/dev/null` and does all the work. Sample code demo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-6.15
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package process
     --package silently
 -}

import System.Process
import System.IO
import System.IO.Silently

writeToStderr :: IO ()
writeToStderr = do
  hPutStrLn stderr "hello"
  hPutStrLn stderr "world"

main :: IO ()
main = hSilence [stderr] writeToStderr
```