# Start-Process redirect output to $null

Tags: powershell

I'm starting a new process like this:

```
$p = Start-Process -FilePath $pathToExe -ArgumentList $argumentList -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait

if ($p.ExitCode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Host = "Failed..."
    return
}
```

And my executable prints a lot to console. Is is possible to not show output from my exe?

I tried to add  `-RedirectStandardOutput $null` flag but it didn't work because `RedirectStandardOutput` doesn't accept `null`. I also tried to add `| Out-Null` to the `Start-Process` function call - didn't work. Is it possible to hide output of the exe that I call in `Start-Process`?

Comment: you can try $ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'   at the top of the script

Answer (score 14):

Using call operator `&` and `| Out-Null` is a more popular option, but it is possible to discard standard output from `Start-Process`.

Apparently, [`NUL` in Windows seems to be a virtual path in any folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27773642/25450). `-RedirectStandardOutput` requires a non-empty path, so `$null` parameter is not accepted, but `"NUL"` is (or any path that ends with `\NUL`).

In this example the output is suppressed and the file is *not* created:

```
> Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow ping localhost -RedirectStandardOutput ".\NUL" ; Test-Path ".\NUL"
False
> Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow ping localhost -RedirectStandardOutput ".\stdout.txt" ; Test-Path ".\stdout.txt"
True
```

`-RedirectStandardOutput "NUL"` works too.

Answer (score 9):

You're invoking the executable *synchronously* (`-Wait`) and *in the same window* (`-NoNewWindow`).

**You don't need `Start-Process` for this kind of execution at all - simply invoke the executable *directly*, using `&`**, the call operator, which allows you to:

- use standard redirection techniques to silence (or capture) output
- and to check automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE` for the exit code

```
& $pathToExe $argumentList *> $null
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
  Write-Warning "Failed..."
  return
}
```

If you still want to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), see [sastanin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623136/45375).