# How to represent an empty / invalid java.nio.Path

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nio, is-empty

How can one create a java.nio.Path that represents **no path** no matter the environment?

I cannot call `Path.of(<String>)` and guarantee the resulting path to point to an invalid file or directory.

What I'm looking for is if there is a safer way to represent an empty / invalid path than using a `null` value.

Comment: maybe you could use /dev/null?

Comment: Yeah, that would work. But what about Windows users?

Comment: I think NUL is reserved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/313115/1873438

Comment: I didn't know windows had such a feature. That's cool! On the other hand, I think it is part of batch syntax more than a file in itself. And this is still system dependent. If I have unit tests on my Linux machine, I would have to change the "invalid file" path when I want to work on Windows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your use case, there are a couple options:

- If you are trying to return the path from a method, you can use `Optional<Path>` and return `Optional.empty()` to denote no path.
- If this is a field in a class and that class implements some behavior, you can use the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) to implement another class with the same interface that does "nothing" (whatever your application needs to do if there is no path).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't really try to create an invalid `Path`. It is not intended to be used that way. 
If you have a function that could return a `Path`, but in certain cases it would not, the best approach is to return `Optional<Path>`.

The advantage is that you will be forcing whoever is calling the function to check for the case where there is no valid `Path`. Unlike returning `null`, where if the caller forgets to check for it, he will just get the program blow up with a `NullPointerException` later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid nulls, use Optional and then you can test for null/present.