# Running command with /dev/null on Windows

Tags: windows, curl, syntax

OK, this question has been asked before (e.g. [Is there a /dev/null on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/is-there-a-dev-null-on-windows)) but I'm trying to find an answer that works, and all of the prior questions just say "change the command to point to NUL"

If I have a curl request (or whatever) which someone ran on a Unix/Mac which includes this:

```
-o /dev/null
```

it will throw an error if I try to run it as-is on my Windows box. Therefore, I need to *change* the command by replacing that with:

```
-o NUL
```

My question is, is there something I can do so that I can run the original curl request without needing to make that change?

IOW, can I create a symlink or something similar, so that I don't *need* to change the curl statement? Basically so I can use the *nix syntax on a Windows box?

Before someone says "how much hassle is it to change the curl", I'm running hundreds of curls a day, often ones which were originally run on a *nix box. Also, if I change to use Windows syntax, then when someone tries to run it on a *nix box, they get issues....

Comment: In Windows, a filesystem symlink isn't allowed to target a character device. (I know in Unix "/dev/null" is a block device and that Unix symlinks aren't limited to disk and filesystem devices.) Even if it could, you'd have to create the link in a "\dev" directory on every drive, if the drive even support symlinks.

Comment: FYI, the root mountpoint for devices is "\\.\" or "\\?\", which get mapped to the NT device mountpoint "\??\", which consists of a local (per logon-session) directory that shadows the global mountpoint directory, "\Global??". Typically "nul" isn't locally shadowed, so "nul" [DOS] -> "\\.\nul" [Windows] -> "\??\nul" [NT] -> "\Global??\nul" [NT]. The latter is an object symlink to the real NT device name, "\Device\Null".

Comment: @eryksun I'll be honest, I didn't completely understand your response (my issue, not yours). LSS, what I want can't be done, it sounds like?

Comment: I don't see a way to support "/dev/null" using a regular symlink. The I/O manager will fail the path reparse if it sees the target isn't a local (or remote if enabled) disk or filesystem device. I think it's possible with a filesystem filter driver, but I don't think anyone has developed one that allows creating virtual files such as a "/dev/null" file on every volume.