# Logstash start successfully but doesn't work

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an index with this settings and mappings.

```
PUT /amazon_products
{
"settings": {
  "number_of_shards": 1,
  "number_of_replicas": 0,
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {}
    }
 },
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "keyword"
     },
    "title": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "manufacturer": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "scaled_float",
      "scaling_factor": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This fields also exist in my **.csv** file and i want to send my data from csv file to **elasticsearch** using  **logstash** . 
This is my logstash config file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "E:\ElasticStack\Logstash\products.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NULL"
   }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["id","title","description","manufacturer","price"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "amazon_products"
  }
  stdout {}
}
```

When if use this command **`.\logstash -f ..\config\logstash.conf`**
The only message from logstash is: 
**Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}** and it doesn't send data to elasticsearch

Please Help Me. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use forward slashes in your path configuration even on windows, also change the `sincedb_path` to `NUL`.

Try this config in your input

```
input {
  file {
    path => "E:/ElasticStack/Logstash/products.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set the `sincedb_path` parameter to "NUL".

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/is-there-a-dev-null-on-windows