# Java: FileOutputStream("NUL:") not working after Java upgrade

Tags: java, windows, dev-null

On Windows, NUL is the null output device similar to /dev/null on Linux.

With Oracle Java 8 **Update 331**, trying to get a `new FileOutputStream("NUL:")` throws an exception. Previously (Java 8u321) it worked fine.

The problem seems to be the colon:

- `new FileOutputStream("NUL")` - OK
- `new FileOutputStream("NUL:")` - exception

Can anyone point me to docs or JDK sources regarding this change? I can't change the code itself because it is in a 3rd party lib (xnio-api).

```
try
{
  new FileOutputStream("NUL:");
  System.out.println("OK");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Just for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/is-there-a-dev-null-on-windows

Comment: Relevant entry in Oracle Bug Database: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8285445

Comment: Fixed in Oracle Java **8u333**

Comment: And for completeness, it's also fixed in the library; `NUL:` has been replaced by `NUL` in [xnio-api 3.8.7.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.xnio/xnio-api/3.8.7.Final) via ticket [XNIO-404](https://github.com/xnio/xnio/commit/4e2db8d397e5798a8ca27315dad3e12e9927e45b)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect [this is the offending change](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/commit/d72d28967d732ba32e02178b828255378c5a8938).

Apparently it tries to avoid accessing ADS (alternate data streams), but seems to "accidentally" also prevent access to device-files like this.

If that's correct, then you can try setting the system property `jdk.io.File.enableADS` to `true` to re-enable the old behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now I need to evaluate the implications of having ADS enabled... :)

Comment: Maybe it helps.
I used the workaround in my wildfly environment, but was not working.
E.g: I started wildfly like "standalone.bat -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true --server-config=my.xml"
But I found, the system property was for the application and not for the JVM.
Adding the system property to standalone.conf.bat like:
  set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true"
This was passed to the JVM.
Standalone.conf looks is passed to the application level (based on order)
(I'm not a wildfly expert, maybe the are more elegant ways.)

Comment: -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true works for me  ,jdk11 on windows11 , thank you