# Problem invoking EJB from with a client that use Java 1.8.0_331

Tags: java, ejb

Switching from Java 1.8.161 to 1.8.0_331 the EJB client stopped working.
The error message is:

```
Apr 25, 2022 8:34:49 AM org.xnio.ChannelListeners invokeChannelListener
ERROR: XNIO001007: A channel event listener threw an exception
java.io.IOError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:998)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:988)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.<clinit>(Channels.java:988)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:403)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:242)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:199)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:113)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$DelegatingChannelListener.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:1092)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:993)
    ... 14 more
```

Here https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u331-relnotes.html
is written that:

The parsing of URLs in the LDAP, DNS, RMI and CORBA built-in JNDI providers as been made more strict. The strength of the parsing can be controlled by system properties

But setting the system property seems do not have effect.
So I would want to know what means "The parsing of URLs as been made more strict"? How it should be?

We use Wildfly 8 as application server. We get the Context with this code:

```
    private static Context createRemoteEjbContext(String host, int port) throws NamingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
        
        String providerURL = "http-remoting://" + host + ":" + port;
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerURL);
        props.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.jboss.remoting3.RemotingOptions.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL", 60000);
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        
        return new InitialContext(props);
        }
```

and from the context we lookup passing this string:

```
    dataloy/dataloy-ejb/BasicServicesEJB!com.dataloy.svc.impl.ejb.BasicServicesHome
```

Any idea?
Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 2):

Theres a bug when you use Wildfly with JDK 11.0.15, just downgrade to version 11.0.14, that worked for our enviroment

Comment: I can confirm this, I had a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to:
[Java: FileOutputStream("NUL:") not working after Java upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966064/java-fileoutputstreamnul-not-working-after-java-upgrade)

> "You can try setting the system property jdk.io.File.enableADS to true
> to re-enable the old behaviour."

There is a bug in this jvm version, that affects the library xnio (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/XNIO-404).

If that doesnt work, you can apply the same patch used in
https://issues.redhat.com/browse/XNIO-404
(I tested copying the class Channels.java and changed the problematic line, so it writes to NUL, as in the issue). Anyway, i will wait for the fix en the jvm bug, and if that is closed without fixing i will apply any of the previous solutions.

**PS:**
It is fixed in 1.8.0_333

Comment: Many thanks Pablo. We will wait the fix

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks Pablo! You have just ended hours of me beating my head against a wall. Upgraded from 331 to 333 and it's resolved.

Comment: It's good that you have added a helpful feedback here, but it would be better if you add a comment instead whenever your reputation allows you to do so.