# JHipster error when I try to connect in the site. Java.lang.noclassdeffounderror

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a problem with my Java project and one of the possible solutions is to change `jdk.io.File.enableADS` to `TRUE` in system properties. But, i don't know how to change it.

I'm also working in a project that uses jhipster and undertow. My project builds with no error, generating the connection link, but when I try to connect the page it doesn't load and the application shows the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xnio.conduits.Conduit
```

I've looked at the code, found the line that throws the error and I saw in many blogs people telling to change the config above the text.

I'm using the JDK 11.0.15

This is the code that throws the error:

```java
 try {
    if (osName.contains("windows")) {
         return new FileOutputStream("NUL:").getChannel();
    } else {
         return new FileOutputStream("/dev/null").getChannel();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new IOError(e);
}
```

Comment: "I'm working on a problem. I found a solution but it doesn't work". This is not a question we can answer in any form, without knowing what either the problem or the proposed solution is.

Comment: What about [How to set system property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/how-to-set-system-property) and similar questions? Do these help?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of details, I changed the problem explanation.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you're running into this problem: [Java: FileOutputStream("NUL:") not working after Java upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966064/java-fileoutputstreamnul-not-working-after-java-upgrade)

The code you're referencing that is causing the problem is from https://code.yawk.at/org.jboss.xnio/xnio-api/3.8.4.Final/org/xnio/conduits/Conduits.java

```
    static {
        NULL_FILE_CHANNEL = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<FileChannel>() {
            public FileChannel run() {
                final String osName = System.getProperty("os.name", "unknown").toLowerCase(Locale.US);
                try {
                    if (osName.contains("windows")) {
                        return new FileOutputStream("NUL:").getChannel();
                    } else {
                        return new FileOutputStream("/dev/null").getChannel();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new IOError(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I've looked at the sources for this release (`3.8.4`) and the most recent release on maven central (`3.8.7`): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.xnio/xnio-api/3.8.7.Final

And there is some good news, it has been fixed in the latest release of `xnio-api`. The current code in version `3.8.7` is now as follows: (`NUL:` was replaced by `NUL`)

```
                    if (osName.contains("windows")) {
                        return new FileOutputStream("NUL").getChannel();
                    } else {
                        return new FileOutputStream("/dev/null").getChannel();
                    }
```

So if it's possible i would suggest you try to upgrade your dependency so that `xnio-api-3.8.7.Final.jar` is used.

**Update 09-2022**
Thanks to the comment of @NicolasRiousset, who found the [following issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/18440) logged on jhipster's github, i have further traced this problematic dependency.

It starts with the `optional` dependency to `spring-boot-starter-undertow`, which in turn depends on `undertow-core`, and that depends on `xnio-api` from Jboss.

The earliest version that includes the fix (`xnio-api-3.8.7`) can be found in [`undertow-core 2.2.18.Final`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.undertow/undertow-core/2.2.18.Final). The earliest version that uses this is [`spring-boot-starter-undertow 2.7.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-undertow/2.7.1).

And JHipster starts including `spring-boot` version >= `2.7.1` from [`jhipster-framework 7.9.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.jhipster/jhipster-framework/7.9.0).

So upgrading to JHipster >= `7.9.0` should fix this problematic `xnio-api` dependency.

In case you don't strictly need `undertow` as your embedded web server, you can also switch (back) to `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, since tomcat doesn't use the `xnio-api`.

---

Otherwise the mentioned system property should indeed also be a valid workaround for now. Since the code is statically loaded, i think you'll have to use VM arguments to include it in your program instead of using `System.setProperty`.

So add `-Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true` to your programs startup/command line.
See for reference the following question that was mentioned in the comments: [How to set system property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189914/how-to-set-system-property)

It does also seem to be fixed in newer version of the Java runtime, so upgrading your JDK/JRE is also an option. According to the linked question at the top it's fixed in Java 8u333, and on my test system with Java 17.0.2 both versions of `NUL` also work.

Comment: Thanks Man, I solved this issue downgrading my JDK version to 11.0.14 insted of 11.0.15

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNeves, thanks, I had same issue and downgrading to 14 also helped me. You can close this ticket I think.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNeves if this solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer as the solution to the question. Thanks!

Comment: There's a ticket opened about this issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/18440
Upgrading to JHipster 
Upgrading from JHipster 7.0.1 to 7.9.3 solved the issue for me

Comment: @NicolasRiousset great find, i have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.  I closed and reopened IntelliJ.  Now it works.  Worth trying before getting too deep down the rabbit hole.